# Extending GitLab Container Scanning Job to run for develop branch only

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've enabled GitLab container scanning by importing the template Security/Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml and adding a container_scanning block

```
container_scanning:
  stage: compliance
  variables:
    DOCKER_IMAGE: $MY_REPO/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://localhost:2375"
```

However, I would like container_scanning job to only execute for develop branch, but the template itself [defines a rule block](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Security/Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml#L46-50), which prevents me from defining an `only` block.

Does anyone know how I can enable the container_scanning job to extend/override the rules block such that it will execute only when a commit is pushed to develop branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the template uses `rules:` you will have to use `rules:` to change the behavior of when the job is included in the pipeline.

```yaml
container_scanning:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
  # ...
```

When you introduce your own `rules:` key, it overrides the existing `rules:` array entirely.